How to check if a domain is registered using whois shell command
I have some trouble with some domains.
The command whois from linux shell says No match for domain but I am expecting the domain results to be registered.
$ whois gnso.com

From the shell whois result:
% whois gnso.com                 
% IANA WHOIS server
% for more information on IANA, visit http://www.iana.org
% This query returned 1 object

refer:        whois.verisign-grs.com

domain:       COM

organisation: VeriSign Global Registry Services
address:      12061 Bluemont Way
address:      Reston VA 20190
address:      United States of America (the)

contact:      administrative
name:         Registry Customer Service
organisation: VeriSign Global Registry Services
address:      12061 Bluemont Way
address:      Reston VA 20190
address:      United States of America (the)
phone:        +1 703 925-6999
fax-no:       +1 703 948 3978
e-mail:       info@verisign-grs.com

contact:      technical
name:         Registry Customer Service
organisation: VeriSign Global Registry Services
address:      12061 Bluemont Way
address:      Reston VA 20190
address:      United States of America (the)
phone:        +1 703 925-6999
fax-no:       +1 703 948 3978
e-mail:       info@verisign-grs.com

nserver:      A.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.5.6.30 2001:503:a83e:0:0:0:2:30
nserver:      B.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.33.14.30 2001:503:231d:0:0:0:2:30
nserver:      C.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.26.92.30 2001:503:83eb:0:0:0:0:30
nserver:      D.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.31.80.30 2001:500:856e:0:0:0:0:30
nserver:      E.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.12.94.30 2001:502:1ca1:0:0:0:0:30
nserver:      F.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.35.51.30 2001:503:d414:0:0:0:0:30
nserver:      G.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.42.93.30 2001:503:eea3:0:0:0:0:30
nserver:      H.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.54.112.30 2001:502:8cc:0:0:0:0:30
nserver:      I.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.43.172.30 2001:503:39c1:0:0:0:0:30
nserver:      J.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.48.79.30 2001:502:7094:0:0:0:0:30
nserver:      K.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.52.178.30 2001:503:d2d:0:0:0:0:30
nserver:      L.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.41.162.30 2001:500:d937:0:0:0:0:30
nserver:      M.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.55.83.30 2001:501:b1f9:0:0:0:0:30
ds-rdata:     19718 13 2 8acbb0cd28f41250a80a491389424d341522d946b0da0c0291f2d3d771d7805a

whois:        whois.verisign-grs.com

status:       ACTIVE
remarks:      Registration information: http://www.verisigninc.com

created:      1985-01-01
changed:      2023-12-07
source:       IANA

# whois.verisign-grs.com

No match for domain "GNSO.COM".
>>> Last update of whois database: 2024-12-05T14:18:26Z <<<



The penultimate line No match for domain "GNSO.COM" indicates that the name  is available.
Checking https://register.com, shows the name is TAKEN. And also other registrars show it taken.
How is it possible that the shell whois command that uses whois.verisign-grs.com server, an iana server, that is

The global coordination of the DNS Root, IP addressing, and other Internet protocol resources is performed as the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) functions

(from their website https://iana.org)
This is one of many domain with the same result. But the research is more extensive.
Can someone explain to me why?

Searching on Stack Overflow you can find this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23996928/correct-command-to-get-domain-whois-info
that explains that there's a way to set your custom hostname whois server with the following command by using the option -h
$ whois -h whois.nic.ru gnso.com
# just an example for putting a different whois server, but “whois.nic.ru“ it's not for .com TLD

Is there a whois server reliable that offers a certain answer to see if a domain is registered?
At the end, how to get the expected result by using whois command?

EDIT
Just to give more examples, another strange result is for $ whois otpi.com
# ....
# last lines are
   Name Server: DNS11.SERVIDORESDNS.NET
   Name Server: DNS12.SERVIDORESDNS.NET
   DNSSEC: unsigned
   URL of the ICANN Whois Inaccuracy Complaint Form: https://www.icann.org/wicf/
>>> Last update of whois database: 2024-12-12T14:42:46Z <<<

# whois.nicline.com

No match for domain otpi.com.

No match for domain but is "Registered in 2002" for Namecheap, and also taken for GoDaddy an Wix.

P.S. To all the people who clicked the down arrow I would like to say that it should be clicked if "the question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" and it doesn't seem like that to me at all. Anyway thanks ‍

As far as I know, registrars use their own internal protocol to communicate the "free/taken" domain status with central registry operated by IANA. It is not related to WHOIS. WHOIS data is usually delayed (sometimes quite long) with regard to that data. Maybe the domain was registered via a registrar who didn't yet put the data into WHOIS. Maybe the domain has only been reserved and not yet registered (some registrars give such option) and the data won't be in WHOIS until it's actually registered.

@raj I have to say that I don't really agree with what you say about the protocol. If all registrars say it's busy instead of free, it means they are synchronized on something and that something is the whois server. IANA must know whether the domain is registered or not. .......

@raj ...... "Maybe the domain has only been reserved and not yet registered (some registrars give such option)" NEVER HEARD ANYTHING LIKE THIS. Either it is registered or it is not registered. The answer is binary. "Reserved" means that it was registered by someone else who put it up for sale, but it is still registered. So all the data must be on the whois server that serves as the coordinator fore each registrar.

"If all registrars say it's busy instead of free, it means they are synchronized on something and that something is the whois server." Well, yes and no. Yes, they are synchronized on something. No, that something is NOT the whois server. It's an internal server available for registrars only, speaking internal binary protocol (yes/no).
WHOIS is completely independent of this.

@ raj "If all registrars say it's busy instead of free, it means they are synchronized on something and that something is the whois server." Well, yes and no. Yes, they are synchronized on something. No, that something is NOT the whois server. It's an internal server available for registrars only, speaking internal binary protocol (yes/no). WHOIS is completely independent of this.    --> READ THE "ANSWER"

Why do you continue to provide four letter domains as an example? They are 100% taken 20 years ago, they are subject to a different, restrictive process. If you want a four letter domain, or need information about it, you need to contact the owners directly. This forum isn't for your rants about Wikipedia.

@Greg Askew 100% seems like a too large number to me. Most of them were acquired between 10 and 20 years ago (statistically), but some are still free. I apologize for the complaints on Wikipedia. I just said what I thought.
I have no intention of buying any 4-character domain, also because the prices offered by the owners are not for my pocket. And in general I have no intention of buying a domain either. The examples are 4chars why many are taken & it's easier to get feedback. Knowledge is king. Knowing first of all.
Hello colleague of Server Fault.
It's almost Christmas. Be good

AFAIK I know every Top Level Domain should maintain its own Whois servers that you should query explicitly, rather than using the default Whois server built into the whois command.
This response refer: whois.verisign-grs.com says that you should query whois.verisign-grs.com for Whois information regarding domains in the  .com TLD (and not the IANA Whois server ).
In the past I have used jwhois which was way smarter in querying the correct Whois servers for most top level domains.

@ HBruijn MMM. The command you see asks to the iana server that it's exactly whois.verisign-grs.com (so the referer for .com domain). jwhoisit's very interesting for asking to for most top level domains, but it's not a standard linux/unix command Command 'jwhois' not found, did you mean.... The question specifically about the whois. Let's not go out of line.

https://www.joker.com offer a specific WHOIS port for doing this, something they've provided for many years now. You can query it using the below command:
$ whois -h whois.joker.com -p 4343 domain:example.com
And you'll get the response:
domain:example.com registered if registered and
domain:example.com free if not registered.
So you can pipe this to grep -q registered$ or grep -q free$ and look at the exit code via $? to check if this is zero or non-zero for determining if the domain is free or registered.

@ parkamark Thanks finally a worthy answer on the subject also because I can't find anything so specific online. It's quite a complex subject. Apart from this whois.joker.com [which responds on port 4343, which is not exactly that of the whois server (43)] I can't find anything else. .......

@ parkamark ... And then it's not exactly a whois response because the command only responds with registered or not registered (a bit of a blackbox system). Something that offers information on the domain would be necessary, eg who it is registered to, when it was registered etc. The piping part to grep is a surplus. I would prefer to talk more about the service to be honest. Anyway thanks you are the first to have obtained something useful. You could probably get the green tick. Bye

@ parkamark However, this does not provide an answer to why it is not registered on the IANA server when it is actually a registered domain (TAKEN).

@PHPKiatofiaFlowOverUs if that service is only giving the registered/free status, it probably accesses the internal registrar-registry data I have mentioned in the other comment that is different from WHOIS data. It works exactly like this. For some reason the registrar didn't provide WHOIS data for that domain (only that registrar could know why), that's why the data aren't there.

@raj HAHAHHAHAH! I laughed so much . I can't see that data are absent in my output. And what you say it' obvious. if they are not, they are missing!  I am saying that a whois server (like IANA) provides longer answers with domain registration data (server owner data, domain registration date if registered, and everything you see in the output posted in the question). It is a standardized answer. While in practice the registrar whois.joker.com provides a service that can be used with the whois command to provide output. ....

@raj ......... Even the domain:example.com part of the command is not a standardized thing. Test on IANA whois and whois -h whois.verisign-grs.com -p 43 domain:example.com and the output will be No match for domain "DOMAIN:EXAMPLE.COM". If you run a netcat on any port (for example nc -l 1114) and run the command whois -h 127.0.0.1 -p 1114 hello.com you will notice that the query is hello.com. Each one could provide any output for that request.. So it is better if you talk about real whois servers that work with a standard command and give standard answers. Bye

To start with, WHOIS is not an authoritative source of information about whether the domain is registered or not. When you register a domain at most registrars, you even get an explicit information that there may be a delay before your domain appears in the WHOIS database.
The authoritative source is the shared registry for a given TLD (which for .com TLD is operated by Verisign). But the data in that registry is available only for accredited domain registrars and is accessed using Extensible Provisioning Protocol (EPP), which is a successor to Registry-Registrar Protocol (RRP) that was used for this purpose initially.
The only way for a regular user to (indirectly) access registry data is through any of the accredited registrars. When you enter the domain name into a search form on a registrar's website, you are indirectly accessing that data over EPP. So if registrars say that the domain in question (gnso.com) is registered, it means that it exists in the registry. It is unrelated to domain data being available in WHOIS or not.
The fact that the service whois.joker.com mentioned in the other answer displays this domain as registered suggests that this service is also a gateway to access the registry data over EPP. It is not a regular WHOIS service and shouldn't be considered as such.
The only thing we know for sure is that there's a discrepancy between WHOIS data (which shows that the domain gnso.com does not exist) and the registry data, which shows it's registered. Only Verisign can reliably answer the question why for that particular domain there is this discrepancy. It would help if we knew which registrar registered that domain. Maybe there's just some bug in Verisign system that doesn't put domains registered by that particular registrar into WHOIS database.
I don't think that anybody from outside Verisign can answer for sure why this is happening.
Update: I just found out that the page https://whois.domaintools.com/gnso.com says that this domain was previously active, but has expired. Maybe that's an explanation - the domain may be now in the "grace period" waiting for the previous domain owner to have a last chance to renew it. That's why it has been removed from WHOIS but is still marked as unavailable in the registry. If the renewal doesn't occur and the grace period expires, the domain may become available again.

This isn't really an answer, but since it's too long for a comment I'll reply to @raj here.

First of all, congratulations, because you seem to be the most knowledgeable of all about registrars and domains when in my opinion over 99% of server administrators / network administrators have not understood a thing. And I will start by saying that I didn't know anything about the "Extensible Provisioning Protocol (EPP)".
☝️ In any case I don't understand how it's possible that querying (and not modifying) the shared TLD registry is only allowed to registrars. It should be allowed to everyone directly and not through what you call a "gateway" (eg whois.joker.com).
Actually I've never heard of this "guarantee time" for expired domains. Unfortunately I don't own any domains, so I don't know exactly how these things work .
Instead I discovered that this specific domain can be registered with some registrars
Look @ https://www.serverplan.com/order-wizard/step1?op_type=verifyDomainBlock&domain_string=gnso&ext_string=com (accredited registrar).
The absurd thing is that other big names like Namecheap, Hostinger, GoDaddy claim that it is registered!
I also saw that it was previously active, but has expired according to some other registrar services, I don't remember where because I did a lot of tests in this days ( it was probably the one in your link https://whois.domaintools.com/gnso.com )
The only thing I'm really not sure about is that the whois does not exactly reflect what is on the shared registry. I should find out more about it, but the online documentation creates a hallucinatory mental confusion. I can't find any truly comprehensible information on the subject. Also because since I have no idea what the heck this shared domain registry practically is or how exactly a registrar makes a request to this registry with the protocol you mentioned, I feel like I'm groping in the dark.
As for the fact that Verisign is the only one who knows something, this is a certainty, because for the TLD domains .com, from what I understand, the reference IANA whois server is Verisign: whois.verisign-grs.com.
In any case, thanks for your reply because at least you have shed some light on the subject. 

Maybe just accidentally you found the registrar that has initially registered the domain. Technically they still "own" the domain, so they can re-register it for another user, while other registrars cannot. If you read the linked Wikipedia article about EPP, you'll see that one of the response codes registry server can return to the query from registrar is "redemptionPeriod", explained as "registrar has asked the registry to delete your domain. Your domain will be held in this status for 30 days." This may be the case with that domain.

Also see in the same link, a description for EPP "delete" command: "Hosts and Contacts are deleted immediately, while domains mostly change into a redemption grace period." This may explain why the domain is not in the WHOIS, because as I understand, what you see in WHOIS are exactly "hosts" (nameservers) and contacts for the domain.

@ raj - COMMENT 1 - I read everything on Wikipedia, but honestly I understood very little. I have a lot to study. 1) For the "redemptionPeriod" in response I will try in 28/30 days. 2) Among all the registrars in the world (probably over 10000) in your opinion I found exactly one Italian registrar that registered a .com domain. I think you are shooting high.

@ raj - COMMENT 2 - For the second comment, when you talk about the EPP delete command and the fact that hosts are deleted and "contact immediately while domains mostly change into a redemption grace period" I repeat, I will do a whois on the same domain again in ~30 days to see for sure (it is really the worst case scenario) and I will tell you if it is as you say, but in my opinion the domain is not registered and it is not even in redemption period if someone allows to register it. And also in my opinion whoever allows to register it owns many other domains, but absolutely not that one!

@ raj Now I don't read anymore about anything. Not on Wikipedia or anywhere else. A mental break is needed. Too many links, too much informationm too much attempts. In 30 days you will have an answer. THE QUESTION IS NOT CLOSED REGARDLESS OF EVERYTHING.
